# best way to check link video in javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, algorithm

I have a list of facebook video link and I need to make a playlist of it in javascript

But I need to check if it is valid link , if I can embed the video for each link before playing each video

Should I use recursive function to do that ?

**EDIT :**

Here a short code of my code really dirty

```
var myEventHandler = my_video_player.subscribe('finishedPlaying', function(e) {
    console.log('end of the video ');

    if(i == nb_video -1){
        console.log('no more video 1');
        $.get('/playlistVideos', function(data){
            i = 0;
            video = JSON.parse(data);
            nb_video = video.length;
            $('.fb-video').attr('data-href', video[i].link);

            emptyDiv(); 

            FB.XFBML.parse();   
            my_video_player.play();
        });
    }else{
        i++;
    }

    if(typeof getSecondPart(video[i].link) === "undefined"){
        i++;
    }

    var id = getSecondPart(video[i].link);
    console.log(id);
    console.log('flag 1');
        FB.api(
        id+"?fields=embeddable", { access_token :'XXXXX'},
        function (response) {
            if (response && !response.error) {
                if(!response.embeddable){

                    console.log('video not embeddable');
                    i++;

                    $('.fb-video').attr('data-href', video[i].link);

                    emptyDiv(); 

                    FB.XFBML.parse();
                    my_video_player.play();


                }else{
                    console.log('video is embeddable');
                    var data_href_next_video = video[i].link;

                    $('.fb-video').attr('data-href', data_href_next_video);
                    my_video_player.unmute();
                    FB.XFBML.parse(); // 
                    my_video_player.play();

                    emptyDiv();

                    my_video_player.unmute();

                }
            }else{
                console.log('not embeddable');
                i = i++; 

                console.log('next video >'+video[i].link);
                $('.fb-video').attr('data-href', video[i].link);

                emptyDiv(); 

                FB.XFBML.parse();
                my_video_player.play();

            }
        }
    );  
});
```

Comment: Why recursion? Isn't a loop enough?

Comment: How are you checking if a link is valid? And like @sudomakeinstall2 said, why use a recursive function?

Comment: if the first link is not valid I need to go to the next link and if this one is not valid I need go to the next one ....

Answer (score 0):

I think  you should put all the links in map in sorted order and and then perform a check to do a validation.